# How to use ObjectifyService in Junit Testing

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit, objectify

If you want to use datastore service to perform a junit test, this is what you do

```
LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig(),new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

@Before
public void setUp() {
helper.setUp();
} 

@After
public void tearDown() {
helper.tearDown();
}

@Test
public void testInsert1() {
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
assertEquals(0, ds.prepare(new  Query("yam")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));
ds.put(new Entity("yam"));
ds.put(new Entity("yam"));
assertEquals(2, ds.prepare(new  Query("yam")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));
}
```

i have tried the above test using objectify

```
Public class myofyTest{

@Entity
private class Food{
@id Long id;
String foodtype;

public Food(String food){
 foodtype = food ;
}

}

static{
ObjectifyService.register(Food.class);
}

LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper
(new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig(),new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

@Before
public void setUp() {
helper.setUp();
} 

@After
public void tearDown() {
helper.tearDown();
}

@Test
public void testInsert1() {
Food food = new Food("yam");
ofy().save().entities(food).now();

}
}
```

but i get this kind of exception

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.google.appengine.tools.development.
LocalRpcService: Provider com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.
LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service could not be instantiated
```

How do you implement this kind of test using **ObectifyService** instead of **DatastoreService** ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to add required dependencies.

This is a working test for your question:

```
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;
import com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter;
import com.googlecode.objectify.util.Closeable;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import static com.piyasatakip.backend.OfyService.ofy;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull;

/**
 * Created by devrimtuncer on 27/03/16.
 */
public class ObjectifyServiceTest {


    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

    protected Closeable session;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
        // Reset the Factory so that all translators work properly.
        ObjectifyService.setFactory(new ObjectifyFactory());
        ObjectifyService.register(Food.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.session = ObjectifyService.begin();
        this.helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        AsyncCacheFilter.complete();
        this.session.close();
        this.helper.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void doTest() {
        Food food = new Food("yam");

        // 1) save food to data store
        ofy().save().entity(food).now();

        // 2) retrieve food from data store
        Food foodRetrieved = ofy().load().type(Food.class).filter("foodtype", "yam").first().now();

        assertNotNull(foodRetrieved);
    }

    @Entity
    private class Food {
        @Id
        Long id;

        @Index
        String foodtype;

        public Food(String food) {
            foodtype = food;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add required dependencies.

i.e dependencies at build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.34'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.34'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.34'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.34'

    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.12'

    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'        
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'

    testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.34'
    testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.9.34'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.4'
}
```

Comment: i'm receiving 2 errors. cannot resolve method begin() in `ObjectifyService.begin()` and in method `doTest` in that code of retrieving food, am receiving an error **cannot access com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIterable** at this place `....ofy().load().....`

Comment: @gikarasojo kinene have you checked all the dependencies I've shared?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you didn't have the following lines in your setup()

```
Closable session;
session = ObjectifyService.begin()
```

You will also need this before your helper.tearDown() in your tearDown():

```
session.close();
```