# App Engine Objectify Unit Test Case Persist Data Across Endpoint Call

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, objectify

I have created a unit test case to verify App Engine Endpoint Api call which in turn uses Objectify to store data.

I have defined Objectify as specified in SO answer [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628124/how-to-use-objectifyservice-in-junit-testing). However the user profile created is not persistent across Api calls. The following unit test case fails where as the call expected to pass.

I have verified the Endpoint call and it is working as expected. How to persist the created Datastore object between Api calls?

```
@Test
public void testProfileCreation() throws Exception {

    User user = new User(USER_EMAIL, USER_DOMAIN, "123456789");

    result = profileApi.createProfile( user, profile );

    assertEquals(true, result.getResult());

    User newUser = new User(USER_EMAIL, USER_DOMAIN, "987654321");

    result = profileApi.createProfile( newUser, profile );

    assertEquals(false, result.getResult());

}
```

I have added a cut short endpoint Api call. If a registered email id is used again to register then profile should not be created.

Endpoint Api:

```
public Result createProfile(final User user, final ProfileForm profileForm) 
{
    // Verify profile form
    ....

    Key<Profile> key = Key.create(Profile.class, user.getUserId());
    Profile profile = (Profile) ofy().load().key(key).now();
    if (profile == null) {

        Query<Profile> query = ofy().load().type(Profile.class);
        query = query.filter(String.format("%s %s", "emailId", "="),
                             profileForm.getEmailId());
        if (query.first().now() != null) {
            return new Result(false);
        }

        // Copy profile details from profile form
        profile = new Profile(user.getUserId(), profileForm);
        ofy().save().entity(profile).now();
        result = new Result(true);
    }
    else {
        result = new Result(false);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Profile class

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class Profile {

    @Id
    private String userId;

    private String name;

    @Index
    private String emailId;

    private short count;

    private boolean authorized;
}
```

Comment: can you please post the code how you persist with objectify the data (the User profile)?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer I have added the endpoint call involved.

Comment: the code for saving seems to be ok. Can you maybe please post the code for your User class?

Comment: sorry, you post the class Profile but could you please post the class User?. User user = new User( ..... )

Comment: User is app engine user `com.google.appengine.api.users.User`.

Comment: Hi, I have modified `ConferenceApi.java` and `ConferenceApiTest.java` as above and got the same error in the following example. Something is missing! `https://github.com/udacity/ud859/blob/master/ConferenceCentral_Complete/src/test/java/com/google/devrel/training/conference/spi/ConferenceApiTest.java`.

Comment: your Github link ist not working

Comment: Oops! Sorry. You can refer the following https://github.com/udacity/ud859/tree/master/ConferenceCentral_Complete/src/test